# Replace the content between specific two text lines in a text file using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace the content in a text file between specific two lines. So I'm planing to use reguler expression for this.

here is my `.txt` file

```
text text text text text text
text text text text text text 
text text text text text text
//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-START 
text text text text text text
text text text text text text
//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-END
text text text text text text 
text text text text text text
```

I need to replace the content between `//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-START` and `//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-END`. Here is the C# code im gonna use with regular expression.

`File.WriteAllText("Path", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("Path"), "[Pattern]", "Replacement"));`

So my question is what is the regular expression (`[pattern]`) I can uses here?

Comment: Is regular expression required? How big is input file?

Comment: @pwas: file is few thousand lines. Is there any other batter way?

Comment: I see that you are reading whole file into memory, replacing text and writing whole into output file. I think that better would be to read file line-by-line: if just read line is not your comment, write to output file, otherwise write replacement output.

Comment: @pwas: thank you for the idea. any code sample?

Comment: i've prepared code sample.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya, which content you want replace there? give some replace contents.

Comment: `//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-START 
text text text text text text
text text text text text text
//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-END`

to

`//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-START 
newtext newtext newtext newtext newtext 
newtext newtext newtext newtext newtext 
//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-END`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
(?is)(?<=//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-START).*?(?=//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-END)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I suggest you do in other way (parsing line by line to imporve performance). As I can see you are rewriting  file from input to output only with replaced text, so in my opinion reading whole while into memory has no sense. 
If you don't want use this approach, see Tim Tang answer.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\t\input.txt"))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\t\Output.txt"))
{
    string line;
    var insideDynamicContent = false;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!insideDynamicContent
              && !line.StartsWith(@"//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-START"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
            continue;
        }

        if (!insideDynamicContent)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("[replacement]");

            // write to file replacemenet

            insideDynamicContent = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (line.StartsWith(@"//DYNAMIC-CONTENT-END"))
            {
                insideDynamicContent = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```